# A sufficient condition for a set of primes to be the set of reducibility of an integer polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $P$ be the set of all positive primes. Let $S$ an arbitrary infinite subset of $P$ satisfying the following assumption: there exists a finite Galois extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ and a conjugacy class $C\subset \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $P\setminus S$ is exactly the set of primes unramified in $K/\mathbb{Q}$ whose Frobenius conjugacy class is equal to $C$.

Must there exist a non-constant monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ that is reducible modulo the primes in $S$ and only those primes?

The above assumption is necessary. To see why, take the splitting field of the polynomial and note that the primes modulo which it is reducible are exactly the ramified primes and the unramified primes whose Frobenius conjugacy class does not contain $n$-cycles under the usual embedding of the Galois group into $S_n$ ($n$ is the degree of the polynomial).

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3534817/700841 https://mathoverflow.net/a/352098/145520

Comment: Is there a polynomial which is reducible modulo every prime of the form $4k+1$ except $5$ and $11$?

Comment: @MarkSapir so, just except 5? (maybe $5$ and $13$?)

Comment: Yes, $5, 13$. Using a phone to type leads to misprints.

Comment: $(65 x + 1)(x + 1)$?

Comment: Your polynomial is reducible mod 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes, but you asked about primes of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: I forgot to include iff as in OP.

Comment: I guess that $16900x^2+1$ answers my question above.

Comment: In general if $S$ is a proper set of primes, and $f(x)$ is a polynomial reducible mod $p$ iff $p\in S$, and $p_1,..., p_n$ are in $S$, then let $a=p_1\cdot...\cdot p_n$ and let $g(x)=f(ax)$. Then $g$ is reducible modulo prime $p$ iff $p$ is in $S$ and does not divide $a$.

Comment: The Cebotarev (or Frobenius) density theorem shows that the density is a rational number. The set of primes considered in this question is an example of a Cebotarev set.

Comment: @Pasten: The Chebotarev density theorem is about Dirichlet density of some sets of primes (and it can be an arbitrary nonnegative number).  If the OP meant something else, (s)he should have said it.

Comment: @MarkSapir well, if a set of primes has natural density $\delta$, then it also has Dirichlet density and it is equal to $\delta$. In any case, when people refer to the Cebotarev density theorem they usually mean the version about natural density.

Comment: @MarkSapir The OP does in fact require this in the question! (and it is not Chebyshev's theorem, it's Cebotarev's). If the required monic polynomial exists, then S is a Cebotarev set of primes and the density is a rational number. Of course this is only a necessary condition, while the title asks for a sufficient condition.

Comment: There is no word "Chebotarev" anywhere in the question.

Comment: The word "monic" I did not notice. So $4x^2+1$ and $16900x^2+1$ are not good and my question above is still open.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original question.  The modfied version is quite different.

No. The set of subsets of $P$ satisfying the OP conditions is of  cardinality continuum while the set of polynomials  with integer coefficients is countable.

This answer gives implicite examples. But see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352837/primes-mod-4-and-integer-polynomials), the answer of SashaP there and a comment by GHfromMO for concrete examples.

Comment: "Not always". The OP's question is ambiguous on whether it means "does it exist for every $S$" or "does it exist for some $S$" (without thinking I actually understood the second meaning and the first meaning doesn't make a serious question according to your remark).

Comment: To make things somewhat less trivial, what if we restrict to $S$ that is decidable, i.e. such that there exists an algorithm for determining whether or not a given integer is in $S$?

Comment: Answer: no.  There must be an algorithm for deciding membership in $S$ of time complexity no worse than that for determining whether the given polynomial factors mod $p$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: The OP does not know much about the question. It could be that there is no polynomial reducble mod $p$ iff $p$ is 1 mod 4 except 5 and 13.

Comment: In fact if $S$ is just the set of all primes of the form $4k+3$ then what is the polynomial? For $4k+1$ it is $x^2+1$.

Comment: $x^2+1$ is reducible mod $2$ as well as the primes $4k+1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: $4x^2+1$ then?

Comment: $4 x^2 + 1$ is a unit mod $2$, so I don't know if that counts as irreducible.

Comment: 1 is  an irreducible polynomial by definition, as is any constant.

Comment: Depends.  Many authors disagree, and require an irreducible polynomial to be non-constant (or, over a ring, not a unit).  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) for example.

Comment: The OP has to decide what is an irreducible polynomial. But since he disappeared, I prefer the more convenient definition.

Comment: I haven't yet seen any serious textbook choosing the convention that a nonzero constant polynomial is irreducible (or that $1$ is prime).

Comment: The terminology in "serious" textbooks on ring theory is   beyond good and evil. For example "noncommutative rings" in these books means rings that are not necessarily commutative. So commutative rings are non-commutative. The same happens to associative/non-associative. I understand why 1 is not a prime number but calling 1 composite and polynomial 1 reducible is extremely bad.