# Primes mod 4 and integer polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have asked these questions as comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352105/a-sufficient-condition-for-a-set-of-primes-to-be-the-set-of-reducibility-of-an-i/352109#352109) (these are related to the question there). The questions are: Let $S$ be one of the following sets of primes:

1. All primes of the form $4k+1$ ;
2. All primes of the form $4k+3$;
3. All primes of the form $4k+1$ except $5, 13$;

Is there a monic integer polynomial which is reducible mod prime $p$ iff $p\in S$.

Comment: $x^2+1$ is reducible mod $p$ iff $p=2$ or $4$ divides the order of $(Z/p)^*$, iff $p=2$ or has the form $4k+1$. This is fairly close to (1), but I understand from (3) that you really mean the given subset and not the subset modulo finitely many exceptions.

Comment: $x^2+1$ was suggested as a comment in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352105/a-sufficient-condition-for-a-set-of-primes-to-be-the-set-of-reducibility-of-an-i/352109#352109 . After it was noticed there that it is reducible $\mod 2$, I suggested $4x^2+1$ but it is not monic, unfortunately.

Comment: Please give some context for these questions. In particular, what kind of mathematical problem leads you to be interested in all primes of the form $4k+1$ except 5 and 13?

Comment: @KConrad: The motivation is the question linked to in the OP. That question had a trivial and implici (my)  answer. So a concrete example would be good. $4k+1$ can be replaced by any arithmetic progression containing infinitely many  primes, of course (these sets have positive density and I do not know the answer for any of these sets of primes ). But this snswer (if correct) shows that these sets are indeed, the required explicit examples.

Comment: Exactly what property of $5$ and $13$ makes them exceptional? Interestingly, I also have an open problem which deals with primes $p\equiv1\pmod 4$, $p\notin\{5,13\}$, and I wonder whether there is any relation.

Comment: @Seva: $5, 13$ are random prime numbers =1 mod 4 . I do not know the answer for any finite set of exceptions, including the empty set and sets consisting of one prime. As for $4k+1$, it is also random arithmetic progression (loosely associated with the polynomial $x^2+1$).

Comment: @GHfromMO: I do not understand neither the part before "so" nor the part after "so". Is this a justification for $4k+1$ or an answer for $4k+3$?

Comment: @MarkSapir:  Let us call a set of primes $S$ splitting if there exists a polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $p\in S$ if and only if $f(x)$ splits into linear factors modulo $p$. It is known that $S$ is infinite, and its relative density among primes is $1/|G|$, where $G$ is the Galois group of the splitting field of $f(x)$. The intersection of two splitting sets is a splitting set. It is also known that the primes $p\equiv 1\pmod{d}$ plus certain prime divisors $p\mid d$ form a splitting set. Hence a set of primes $p\equiv a\pmod{d}$ can only be splitting when $a\equiv 1\pmod{d}$.

Comment: @GHfromMO: in your definition of "splitting set of primes" you want splitting into linear factors? If so, it is not the same as "reducible sets of primes" in the OP. I think the new version of SashaP's answer deals precisely with that issue.

Comment: @MarkSapir: You are right, I overlooked this. At any rate, my comments about splitting prime sets yield that, for any $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and any positive integer $d$, there exists a prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{d}$ such that $f(x)$ mod $p$ splits into linear factors. This yields a negative answer to your second question.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Thank you! I understand now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to argue without showing directly that the polynomial must have degree $2$. It was explained to me by Borys Kadets (all further mistakes are, of course, my contribution).

**Lemma.** If a set of primes $S$ of density $\frac{1}{2}$ admits such polynomial then some subset $S'\subset S$ with $\#(S\setminus S')<\infty$ admits a monic *quadratic* polynomial that is reducible precisely at $S'$.

*Proof.* Suppose that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ satisfying the condition for the set $S$. Let $G$ be the Galois group of its splitting field coming with an embedding $G\subset S_n$. By Chebotarev density, exactly $\frac{1}{2}\# G$ elements of this group must be cycles of length $n$.

Since the centralizer of a length $n$ cycle $\sigma\in S_n$ is the subgroup generated by $\sigma$, the number of conjugacy classes of length $n$ cycles in $G$ is $\frac{n}{2}$. In particular, $n$ is even and $G\cap A_n$ has index $2$ in $G$ with cycles of length $n$ forming the non-trivial coset.

The subgroup $G\cap A_n\subset G$ corresponds to a degree $2$ extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$. If a prime $p$ is ramified in the splitting field of $f$ then $f$ is reducible modulo $p$. For any unramified prime $p$ the polynomial $f$ is reducible modulo $p$ iff the Frobenius element of a prime above $p$ in the splitting field is not a length $n$ cycle, the latter condition being equivalent to the fact that $p$ is split in $K$. Thus, the set of primes split (including ramified) in $K$ is equal to $S$ with the possible exception of a finite set of ramified primes.

The minimal polynomial of a generator of $\mathcal{O}_K$ satisfies the conclusion of the lemma. $\square$

Starting with any of the three sets $S$ the lemma gives a quadratic polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ that is reducible precisely at the primes from a set $S'$. Since we want it to be irreducible mod $2$, both $a$ and $b$ have to be odd.

This polynomial is irreducible modulo $p>2$ if and only if $D:=a^2-4b$ is not a square mod $p$.

Set 2: The number $(-D)$ is supposed to be a non-residue modulo all but finitely many primes, but that's impossible. This can be shown by a counting argument: if there was a finite set of primes $p_1,\dots, p_k$ such that $D+n^2$ is a product of powers of $p_i$'s then there would be $O((\log N)^k)$ numbers of the form $D+n^2$ in the interval $[1,\dots, N]$.

Sets 1 and 3: Here we want $(-D)$ to be a square modulo all but finitely many primes. That forces it to be a square in $\mathbb{Z}$. However, setting $-D=c^2$ gives $a^2+c^2=4b$. That is impossible for odd $a$.

Comment: 1) Why does the Chebotarev density theorem implies that the degree should be 2?

2) In the last paragraph, what are $a,b,c$? 

3) Also in the last paragraph, why $-D$ is a square mod all but finitely many primes if $S=\{p| p=4k+1\}$?

Comment: @MarkSapir For primes in $S$, $D$ is a square residue, and $-1$ is a square residue, while for primes not in $S$, $D$ is not a square residue, and $-1$ is not a square residue (with finitely many exceptions). Therefore, for all primes, $-D = -1*D$ is a square residue (with finitely many exceptions).

Comment: @SashaP: Your answer only proves that quadratic polynomials won't work?

Comment: Yes, you're right. This comes down to a problem in group theory that I'm not sure how to solve.

Comment: @SashaP: What problem?

Comment: @MarkSapir To show that the existence of a subgroup in $S_n$ with precisely half of its elements being cycles of length $n$ forces $n=2$, as stated in the second paragraph of the edited answer.

Comment: @SashaP: It is probably known. You can ask  a separate question on MO.

Comment: @SashaP: I thought a little about your problem. The answer is probably unknown but can be checked for small $n$ using GAP or Magma. Say, for $n\le 7$.

Comment: @MarkSapir The existence of such subgroup forces $n$ to be a power of two. Either way, there is an argument around it for your original question, see the edits.

Comment: @YCor Sure, corrected

Comment: @SashaP: looks good now. I need to educate myself about Frobenius elements. Then I will accept the answer.

Comment: Why is the answer "Community Wiki"?

Comment: Why must exactly $1/2$ the elements of $G$ correspond to cycles of length $n$?  I would have thought that the condition is that $1/2$ the elements have at least one fixed point, and $1/2$ the elements have none.

Comment: @Lucia: By Chebotarev theorem there must be a cycle type that occurs 1/2 of the time. So it is stronger than what you wrote. But, indeed, it is not immediately clear why this type is the cycle of max length.

Comment: @MarkSapir:  I only see that half the time there must be a fixed point, and half the time not.  Why must there be a cycle type occurring 1/2 the time?

Comment: If the set is of density 1/2 there should be a cycle type occurring 1/2 of the time. It is in the Wikipedia article on Chebotarev theorem.

Comment: @SashaP: Can you answer Lucia's question?

Comment: Ah ok -- I misread the problem thinking that $f$ is assumed to have no roots mod p for $p$ not in $S$.  Instead the problem gives you that $f$ is irreducible for these primes.  So what you have is fine of course.

Comment: @Lucia: Now that you understood, could you explain it to me? Why does the Galois group contain a big cycle?

Comment: @MarkSapir:  If the polynomial factors in $F_p[x]$ as $f_1 ... f_r$ with $f_i$ of degree $d_i$, then this corresponds to a conjugacy class in the Galois group with cycles of length $d_1$, $\ldots$, $d_r$.  In your problem you had $f$ being irreducible for a bunch of primes; the Frobenius for these primes is therefore an $n$-cycle.

Comment: @Lucia:  Thank you!

Comment: Vefa Goksel informed me that the group theory problem about a permutation group  where 1/2 of the elements are  big cycles has been solved in "Goksel, V. Markov processes and some PCF quadratic polynomials. Res. number theory 5, 29 (2019)" (see  Theorem A in section 4 of the paper).